# How to support both support library and androidx apps in android library?

Tags: android, user-interface, migration, android-support-library, androidx

I have a library which provides few Android fragments that extend `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`. Since support library is not supported by Google anymore it's recommended to migrate to `androidx`.

However it forces partners applications that use the library also migrate to `androidx` which can be undesired due to different reasons (eg. approved releases schedule). What is the best option to support **both** partners who are still on support library and those who already migrated to androidx?

The options i have:

- migrate to androidx

  - pros

    - we will have to do it anyway as support library is announced to be frozen
  - cons

    - there are some partners who can still use support library (not androidx). So they will have to migrate too or live with current version of the library until they migrate
- provide compatibility (adapting) layer (switch between support library and androidx)

  - pros

    - partners will be able to choose what to use by just importing the right module
    - no branch needed, all partners support
  - cons

    - more work (introducing a new compatibility layer and 2 impls)
    - 1 more module to import on partner side (build.gradle), need to explain it to them
- separate branches

  - pros

    - the simplest solution
  - cons

    - partners have to choose between the branches
    - more complicated to import (need to update settings module name) or compile locally
    - much harder to maintain on our side (cherry-pick all the changes to both branches when implemented)

Missed anything? Better ideas?

Comment: I think you can't do much about it and separate into two branches and explain your users. If a user of your library migrates to jetpack androidx and keeps the an older version of your library he would put need `android.enableJetifier` in his gradle.properties file as stated here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx